# R: how to find the name of variable in a table()

Tags: r, subset

Suppose I have

```
    arr = c("JFK", "LAX", "LAX", "SFO", "SFO")
    dep = c("LAX", "JFK", "SFO", "JFK", "JFK")
    tt = table(arr, dep)
```

And tt looks something like

```
         dep
    arr   JFK LAX SFO
      JFK   0   1   0
      LAX   1   0   1
      SFO   2   0   0
```

And then I subset my table

```
     tt2=tt[1:2, 1:2]
```

That returns

```
        dep
    arr   JFK LAX
      JFK   0   1
      LAX   1   0
```

And I wish to know which `arr` are in this subsetted table. It should be "JFK" and "LAX". I tried using `tt2$arr` and `tt2[arr]` but they do not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "JFK" and "LAX" are the row names of table `tt`.

You can access row names with:

```
rownames(tt)
[1] "JFK" "LAX"
```

or

```
dimnames(tt)$arr
[1] "JFK" "LAX"
```

PS: It is `colnames` for column names or `dimnames(tt)$dep`.

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
dimnames(tt[1:2, 1:2])
```

or

```
dimnames(tt2)
```